# Create 2 groups under vertx cluster.xml

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x

How to have multiple group in the cluster.xml? I want to create 2 groups, one for production and the other one for dev.

```
   <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
```

Also, can I specify different ip interface for different groups?

```
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
   <!-- <interface>192.168.133.141</interface> -->
</tcp-ip>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about vertex, but if it is a regular hz file, then you can do e.g.

```
<group>
    <name>${groupname}</name>
    <password>${password}</password>
</group>
```

And provide groupname/password on the commandline as system property: -Dgroupname=foobar. You can apply the same technique for your other question.